# I need help processing data form a table PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I am creating a system for a website that will allow the admin of the website to accept and reject new user registrations from the admin panel.

The table will look something like **NOT the actual table, this is an example**:

```
<th>Username</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Real Name</th> <th>Checkbox</th>
<button>Activate User</button>    <button>Delete User</button>
```

The checkbox is an actual checkbox in the real table.

When the admin logs in and goes to accept users I have an SQL command to collect all users that are not activated and shows them in the example table above.

What I want to know is, using the checkbox on the table, how can I allow the admin to check the checkbox to select multiple users and then either accept them or delete them? I know the SQL command I need to use and everything else but I just don't know how to set up the table so that when the checkbox is checked either on a single user or multiple users that all of their data is processed and the action is actually taken e.g. the user is activated or deleted.

P.S. Sorry, I realised it is supposed to be a form. My bad!

Comment: yes we know its a table, but if you want that to be processed you really need a form, unless you submit it thru ajax. anyway, just select loop print all of the not activated users, echo their ids into the checkbox as values, submit the form, gather all checked values and process them accordingly to make an sql query. still along ways from a code, too broad anyway

Comment: PS: StackOverflow is not a coding service where you can demand that people produce code to your specifications. Most users expect those asking questions to have put some effort into solving the problem themselves, and to show the code that they have written so far. Please see [how to ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Ghost Thanks, I just noticed it is supposed to be a form... I changed the question. The thing I want to know is how do I process the users that are ticked rather than just all of them? I can't seem to figure out a way of doing it where the data is processed properly.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Whilst I am aware it is not the best question ever to grace the Stack Exchange servers I will point out that in no way am I asking people to code my applications for me. In fact, I am not asking to produce any code at all. I am simply asking for logic for the table/form to process the information. Any code is a bonus and greatly appreciated. My comment on code is purely there for people who produce any code. I might change that to make it clear.

Comment: @ASweatyWombat actually is quite straightforward, just make sure that the checkboxes themselves accepts multiple checks, i.e. `name="usernames[]"`, then after submission your post values should return an array, then in PHP you could delete either one by one or using an in clause in the query. just make sure all inputs are escaped

Comment: What research have you done on how forms work? Have you thought about what information the form needed to pass to the server that you can then use to run your sql query? It can help to think backwards from the query--you're going to need a list of user IDs, the action that is to be taken, etc.

Comment: @Ghost That's the solution I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: @ialarmedalien Solution found thanks to Ghost. To activate the users I need to know their ID and username for the purpose of finding them on the database table. Then once I check the user on the table all I need to do is run the UPDATE command and change a row called activated from 0 to 1. I knew exactly what I needed I just didn't think of processing each user on the form using a variable and then passing it to an array. I'll probably use a for each function though.

Comment: @ASweatyWombat oh okay, well thats just the bit of it update 1 or 0 where ids in (userids in here), thats just probably the answer, just without the codes hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you should use `[]` (array of checkbox). ex.

**HTML :**

```
while (iterate through registration requests) {
    echo "<input name='users[]' value='$user_id' type='checkbox'>"; 
}
```

While in backend you can get all checkbox's values as,

**PHP :**

```
$users = $_POST['users'];  // you have an array of all checked checkbox's values
$users_list = "'". implode("','", $users) ."'";
```

here, in `$users_list`, you'll have list of users. eg. `'user1','user2','user3','users4', .....`

Then you can run query to mark all users as registered. ( pseudo query)

```
UPDATE table_name SET approved = '1' WHERE user_id IN ($users_list);
```

you can also use above logic to delete requests also.

Comment: no need to loop, just glue/implode them by comma

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Thank you for your answer with code. I had planned on using a for each function. I will try your method as well. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it hepled you .. happy coding :)